# Firebase array alternative

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase can't accept an array of values so I came up with an idea for each value to be added to it's own individual key. Every time a new value is entered the key get's an incremented count added to the end of it.

i.e.

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorNameTextField: UITextField!

var increaseColorKey = "colorKey"
var count = 0

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

@IBAction func sendToFirebaseButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let newCount = count += 1
    let newKey = increaseColorKey + String(newCount)

    var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
    dict.updateValue(self.colorNameTextField.text!, forKey: "newKey")

    let colorRef = self.ref.child("colors")
    colorRef.updateChildValues(dict)

    let dictKey = Array(dict.keys)
    print("\(newKey)")  //prints colorKey1
    print("\(dictKey)") //prints ["colorKey1"]
}
```

Inside Firebase I would now have

```
root
  |
  @--colors
         |__colorkey1: "user text.."
```

If the user entered 3 colors on 3 separate occasions then the Firebase outcome would be:

```
root
  |
  @--colors
         |__colorkey1: "user text..."
         |__colorkey2: "user text..."
         |__colorkey3: "user text..."
```

*The problem I see with the way I'm doing it now would be if the user switched devices then the count variable above could be completely different from the count that's inside Firebase.*

**The questions are should I have a count value already in firebase and then pull that first and increment from there or should I do it another way? How can I get around this?**

Comment: You should do a colors.count to see how many values are there and then append to that! Also check this url for implementing arrays in firebase -> https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: I'd recommend following [Firebase's documentation for adding nodes to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). There are many reasons why Firebase recommends against using arrays in its database, [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) lists a few of them.